# Регулярное выражение от 0 до 999 с плавающей точкой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Cразу попрошу вас не закидывать меня помидорами, а подсказать, как можно объединить два регулярных выражения:

1. `^[(\d)(\d+\.?,?\d+)]+$` - разрешен ввод только цифр (с плавающей точкой точкой или без неё).
2. `^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|999)$` - разрешен ввод цифр от 0 до 999.

Суть в том что никак не могу объединить эти два выражения. В идеале надо ввести любое число от 0 до 999 с плавающей точкой или без нее. Например 233,832.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})(\.\d+)?$
```

Здесь:

```
^ — начало строки
(X|Y) — соответствие либо X либо Y, т. е.
    (0|[1-9]\d{0,2}) — либо одиночный 0, либо цифра [1-9] и 0-2 любых цифры после нее
\.\d+ — точка и любое количество цифр после нее
(...)? — наличие того что в скобках не обязательно
$ — конец строки
```

Тест: https://regex101.com/r/1M9udl/1

Ну и следует определиться допустимо ли добавлять ведущие нули и опускать незначащие нули, если так, то можно написать что-то вроде:

```
^(\d{1,3}(\.\d*)?|\d{0,3}\.\d+)$
```

т. е. здесь проверяется соответствие строки одному из двух шаблонов:

```
\d{1,3}(\.\d*)? — 1-3 любых цифры потом необязательные точка и любое количество цифр
\d{0,3}\.\d+ — 0-3 любых цифры, затем обязательные точка и хотя бы одна цифра
```

Тест: https://regex101.com/r/TVM6Sj/1

Comment: Благодарю, а можете чуть более подробно разъяснить?

Comment: @IlonMask, дополнил

Answer (score 1):

Может не самый лучший вариант не лишённый изъянов, но пусть тоже будет, вдруг кому пригодится:

```
^(?:999(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Rzf3Ri/1